# Matching all URL variants using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I saw this regex to match and replace urls.

```
$string2= preg_replace("#\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))#", "", $string2);
```

It works fine for most url formats except: example.com (ie. urls without http and www).

Have tried to tweak it to make it match all the example.com formats but no success.

Kindly help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
$string2= preg_replace("#\b(([\w-]+://)?(www[.])?[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))#", "", $string2);
```

I have messed up your grouping though, so you might need to fix that again..

Comment: But basically you want to match anything with a .com/net etc.

Comment: Only http? Or other protocols aswell?